# Extend text on hover

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm  using two initials and I want that if a user hovers it it will show the rest of the text but I can't make it to display the rest of the text correctly: the part of the first letter it's being displayed next to the text of the second initial.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dvxva4sp/1/)

```
#logo .short{
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 0;
        padding: 0 10px;
        font-size: 36px;
        display: inline-block;
        text-transform: uppercase;
      transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
  .short:after{
   position: relative;
    margin-left: -20px;
    content: "est1";
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

 .short:hover:after{
        opacity: 1;
        display: inline-block;
      margin-left: -10px;
 }
#logo span{
    position: relative;
    transition: margin .3s ease-out;
}
span:hover{
        margin-left: 20px;
}
span:after{
   position: relative;
    margin-left: -20px;
    content: "est2";
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
 }

span:hover:after{
  opacity: 1; 
  margin-left: -10px;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set both letters within `<span>` element, use `:nth-of-type()` selector to set `content` of `:after` pseudo element

```css
#logo .short {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-size: 36px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

#logo span {
  position: relative;
  transition: margin .3s ease-out;
}

.short span:nth-of-type(1):after {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -10px;
  content: "est1";
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.short span:nth-of-type(1):hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

span:hover {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.short span:nth-of-type(2):after {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 0px;
  content: "est2";
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.short span:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<a id="logo">
  <h1 class="short">
    <span>T</span><span>t</span>
   </h1>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, I used your answer as solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Place the span tag outside of the header tag and simply style the span tag `:after` as follows:

```
span:hover:after{
  opacity: 1; 
  margin-left: 0px;
 }
```

see snippet below

```css
#logo .short{
     position: relative;
     margin-top: 0;
     padding: 0 10px;
     font-size: 36px;
     display: inline-block;
     text-transform: uppercase;
      transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
  .short:after{
   position: relative;
    margin-left: -20px;
    content: "est1";
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

 .short:hover:after{
     opacity: 1;
     display: inline-block;
      margin-left: -10px;
 }
#logo span{
 position: relative;
 transition: margin .3s ease-out;
}
span:hover{
  margin-left: 20px;
}
span:after{
   position: relative;
    margin-left: -20px;
    content: "est2";
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
 }

span:hover:after{
  opacity: 1; 
  margin-left: 0px;
 }
```

```html
<a id="logo">
   <h1 class="short">
    T
   </h1>
    <span>t</span>
</a>
```